# is there an easy way to disallow some method from framework?

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, deprecated

I want to disallow some method. For example

```
+ (MPMusicPlayerController*)iPodMusicPlayer
```

so i tried to do so:

```
@interface MPMusicPlayerController (Disallowed)
// do never this method cause issues #957 #632 #1463
// read #632 description to detail analysis why code should never use this method while
// applicationMusicPlayer is used
+ (MPMusicPlayerController*)iPodMusicPlayer __attribute__((unavailable));
+ (MPMusicPlayerController*)iPodMusicPlayer __attribute__((deprecated));
@end
```

but code below compiled anyway without any warning

```
MPMusicPlayerController * curPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I find it hard to imagine a situation where this would be the appropriate solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile time solutions:

One way, just use next code:

```
#pragma GCC poison iPodMusicPlayer
```

I should mention SDK61 and SDK7 can not 'poison' selector which contains ':'
cause [llvm bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15931) :(

another way:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> // import original methods at first
@interface MPMusicPlayerController (Disallowed)
+ (MPMusicPlayerController*)disallowedMethod_iPodMusicPlayer __attribute__((unavailable));
@end

#define iPodMusicPlayer disallowedMethod_iPodMusicPlayer
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a category on MPMusicPlayerController, e.g. Override (MPMusicPlayerController+Override), then override the iPodMusicPlayer class method to return nil. Be sure to #include MPMusicPlayerController+Override.h.

You can add a warning mark to your method to remind anyone not to use it:

```
#warning Disabled method - do not use.
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

Damien

Comment: thank you. This method is runtime solution. But compile time solution is preffer.